# android-Memory usage not decrease in Profiler without LeakCanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, android-profiler

I have just started to use LeakCanary. I use this code to avoid memory leak in Fragment.

```
 public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    view = null;
    imageView= null;
    recyclerView= null;
    progressBar = null;
    if (list != null) {
        list.clear();
    }
    recyclerAdapter= null;
    swipeRefreshLayout = null;
}
```

So when I use above codes with LeakCanary I see memory usage is decreasing in Profiler(for example it's decreasing from 120MB to 80MB). But when I remove LeakCanary(from gradle) I see memory usage is not decreasing. It doesn't change(still 120MB). Is it a bug ?